# Can AWS Athena query the content stored in a <struct> column

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto

I have a JSON stored in a file in s3 at `bucket/yyyy/MM/dd/hh`. Content of the file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "orderDetails": {
    "productId": "0afc45s3sde",
    "name": "keyboard",
    "uri": "KeyboardUri"
  }
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Tom",
  "orderDetails": {
    "productId": "2afc65s8sde",
    "name": "Mouse",
    "uri": "MouseUri"
  }
}
```

When I create a table in Athena using AWS Glue crawler, it creates a table with the following attributes:

```
id(int)
name(string)
orderDetail(struct<...>)
partition_0
partition_1
partition_2
partition_3
```

On executing `select * from db.tablename;` it shows all the records.

I want to know if Athena is capable of querying the content of the column. For example:

I want to fetch the uri present in `orderDetails` for both the users(Id = 1,2). So once the query executes, the output should be:

```
KeyboardUri
MouseUri
```

Is there a way to do this with Athena?

Comment: Use dot to access struct elements: `orderDetails.uri`

Comment: Thanks, @leftjoin. This worked. Able to query now.